# What happens in case the network fails with Supabase? (with Flutter)

Tags: flutter, supabase

I am using Supabase with flutter and need to manage a few error cases:

1> select: in this case I check the network connectivity status before making the call, and in case a ClientException is thrown, I wait for the network state to be back and retry.

2> insert/update: I check the network connectivity before making the call - but am unsure what to do in case of a ClientException. Did the insert/update happen? How will I know? Does Supabase rollback the insert/update in case the network fails before the response is delivered?

What should I be doing to manage network issues with Supabase and Flutter?

Comment: There is no way to truly guarantee that a response was received by the client, so Supabase will not rollback anything once a write happens. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqvBaj8UYz4 You can always query your database from the client to see if the new data exists on the database or not.

Comment: Which is non-trivial. Let's see. For an insert, I will need to set a column (say 'check_write') with a UUID that is saved before attempting the insert. Now if there is a failure, I wait for the internet to be back, and check if a record with check_write == saved UUID, else I reattempt the insert?

Answer (score 0):

@dshukertjr is right. There is no way to guarantee it. The UUID approach seems to be the way to go. See https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest/issues/1424

For multiple writes that make up a transaction, with the current absence of long-running transaction support in Supabase/REST we will need to use database functions, and, sadly, move business logic to the database...